# explicitly link intel icpc openmp

Tags: c++, openmp, intel, icc, scientific-computing

I have the intel compiler install at the following `$HOME/tpl/intel`. When I compile a simple `hello_omp.cpp` with openMP enabled

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
#pragma omp parallel

    {
        std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compile with `~/tpl/intel/bin/icpc -O3 -qopenmp hello_omp.cpp` but when I run I get the following error:
`./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libiomp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

I would like to explicitly link the intel compiler and the appropriate library during the make process without using the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: I think you can use `ld`'s  `-rpath=dir` to bake an extra library search path into your executables.  Not posting as an answer because I'm not sure.  Or you could add the path to a `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/something.conf` and run `ldconfig` to add icpc's library directory to your system library search-paths, if you're on a Linux system or one that also uses `ldconfig` that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 simple solutions for your problem:

1. Linking statically with the Intel run time libraries:
   `~/tpl/intel/bin/icpc -O3 -qopenmp -static_intel hello_omp.cpp`

   - Pros: you don't have to care where the Intel run time environment is installed on the machine where you run the binary, or even having it installed altogether;
   - Cons: your binary becomes bigger and won't allow to select a different (more recent ideally) run time environment even when it is available.
2. Adding the search path for dynamic library into the binary using the linker option `-rpath`:
   `~/tpl/intel/bin/icpc -O3 -qopenmp -Wl,-rpath=$HOME/tpl/intel/lib/intel64 hello_omp.cpp`
   Notice the use of `-Wl,` to transmit the option to the linker.
   I guess that is more like what you were after than the first solution I proposed so I let you devise what the pros and cons are for you in comparison.

Comment: Option 1 works. Using the second option, I still get the same error
`./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libiomp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: The actual path to the iomp5 library might be different from what I put so you might need to adjust it. Furthermore, I'm not sure the `~` sign will work in this context so you might need to replace it with the corresponding full path. Just experiment a bit as it should work.

Comment: `-rpath` needs the absolute path. So `-rpath=$HOME/tpl/intel/lib/intel64` worked for me. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Intel Compiler ships compilervars.sh script in the bin directory which when sourced will set the appropriate env variables like LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LIBRARY_PATH and PATH with the right directories which host OpenMP runtime library and other compiler specific libraries like libsvml (short vector math library) or libimf (more optimized version of libm).